# What does the solution to a wave equation represent?

Tags: waves

What does the solution of a wave equation represent? When one finds a solution to a wave equation, how can one interpret this solution? Does the solution show the behavior of a wave?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! What are your thoughts on that? What have you already found? Please note that you are expected to have thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question. And it's important to detail where you're stuck and why, in order to attract good answers. You can consider checking the [advice on writing good questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the usual wave equation,

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} - v^2 \nabla^2 u = 0$$

$u = u(x,t)$ is taken to be some property of the wave, at position $x$ and time $t$. For example, for the electromagnetic wave equation, $E(x,t)$ would be the force per unit charge at $(x,t)$.

If we had a rope, and a wave $u(x,t)$ propagated along the rope, then we could define $u(x,t)$ as the displacement of the infinitesimal piece of rope along it at position $x$, at the instant $t$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the solution of the 1D wave equation:

$f(x,t) = A e^{i (k_x x - \omega t)} + B e^{-i (k_x x - \omega t)}$

If you, an observer, are sitting at the point $x=5$ at time $t=2$, then you feel perturbation $f(5,2)$, while your buddy at $x=3$ at the same time feels $f(3,2)$.

Now, this description is not universal and sometimes completely wrong. The reason for that is that physical meaning of the wave equation depends on what kind of system you are working on. Is it a wave in a string? Dirac equation? Maxwell wave equation? Next time, please, provide details on the contexts. The same mathematical tools can be applied in numerous different ways in Physics.

For instance, for In QM, the solution of the Schroedinger equation $\psi(\vec{r}, t)$ does not have a physical meaning at all, but only its norm $|\psi(\vec{r}, t)|$, which is a probability (density) to find a particle in a particular point in space and time.